# can't view graph via Tensorboard

Tags: python-3.x, tensorboard

I am new in TensorFlow, and can't view my graph.

```
`a = tf.add(1, 2,)
 b = tf.multiply(a, 3)
 c = tf.add(4, 5,)
 d = tf.multiply(c, 6,)
 e = tf.multiply(4, 5,)
 f = tf.div(c, 6,)
 g = tf.add(b, d)
 h = tf.multiply(g, f)
 with tf.Session() as sess:
    writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("log", sess.graph)
    print(sess.run(h))
 writer.close()
```

Then I type
    `Tensorboard --logdir log`

and have 
`TensorBoard 0.1.4 at http://lpt00:6006 (Press CTRL+C to quit)`,
but on this page I see only text "Tensorboard: Inactive"